# array filters in angularjs not working

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

I am trying to display only the names of my array elements with angular but it is not working, can you please help? here is the code:

```html
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController" ng-model="myData">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in myData.items"
               ng-click="myData.doClick(item, $event)">{{myData.item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
                $scope.myData = {};
                $scope.myData.items = [{ name: "1"}, { name: "2"}, { name : "3"} ];

                $scope.myData.doClick = function(item, event) {
                    alert("clicked: " + item.name + " @ " + event.clientX + ": " + event.clientY);
                }


            } );
</script>
```

Comment: `{{myData.item.name}} ` instead of this you have to write this  `{{item.name}} `

Answer (score 3):

You just have to write in the expression as below
`{{item.name}}`